# Make Calendar as 2D Array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a calendar as a HTML table. It should be a single 2D array with each row as a week and each column as a day. The Week start needs to be a Monday and there must be blank spaces for overlapping months.

The Issue is the Start Days are wrong for every month and differently wrong each time. January 1st 2019 was a Tuesday so i expect the Start Day to be a 2, however i get 4 (a Thursday), the same issue is for every other month.

I am using functions to get the amount of days in the month and the day the month starts on

```
function month_days(month, year) {return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();}
function month_start(month, year) {return new Date(year, month, 0).getDay();}
```

My problem is with the month_start function.

```
//date is an date object generated on the fly using date.setMonth() and date.setYear();
var month_2D_arr = gen_days(date.getMonth()+1, date.getFullYear());

function gen_days(month, year){
  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var checking = new Date(year, month, 0);
  console.log(monthNames[checking.getMonth()]);
  console.log(checking.getFullYear());

  var days = mondays(month, year);
  var start = monstart(month, year);
  console.log("start="+start);
}
```

The outputs are as follows (I induced the actual day names manually) compared to what the are suppose to be (to the right of "||").

```
    My Results            ||       Actual Days
January = 4 - Thursday    ||   January = 2 - Tuesday
February = 4 - Thursday   ||   February = 5 - Friday
March = 0 - Sunday        ||   March = 5 - Friday
April = 2 - Tuesday       ||   April = 1 -Monday
May = 5 - Friday          ||   May = 3 - Wednesday
June = 0 - Sunday         ||   June = 6 - Saturday
July = 3 - Wednesday      ||   July = 1 - Monday
August = 6 - Saturday     ||   August = 4 - Thursday
September = 1 - Monday    ||   September = 0 - Sunday
October = 4 - Thursday    ||   October = 2 - Tuesday
November = 6 - Saturday   ||   November = 5 - Friday
December = 2 - Tuesday    ||   December = 0 - Sunday

Example console log:
December //(month)
2019     //(year)
start=2  //(start day)
```

I have also switched set/getFullYear() to set/getYear() accounting for the 1900 difference and checking still. There is no difference to it.

Comment: _“so i expect the Start Day to be a 2, however i get 4 (a Thursday)”_ - that’s probably because the month you are looking at is February, not January. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax

Comment: @04FS February should be a 5 not a 4. If it was a simple offset i could easily correct the month offsets. i know getMonth()+1 gets the next month but setting day to 0 gets the last day of the previous month. so new Date(2019, 1, 0) is 31st January 2019 rather than February.

Comment: @04FS actually that solved my issue. I was getting the day of the last day of the month not the first day.

Answer (score 0):

Been playing with a calendar for giggle this week, so perhaps I can offer some help.

JS uses Sunday(0) as the first day of the week, yet you'd also like to use Monday(1)
You can create a date object that corresponds to the first day of any given month and then from that, you can deduce the day of the week of the 1st.

The approach I've employed was to create a table with 7 rows and 7 columns. The first row only contains th elements with the day names in em.

The next 42 table-cells can then be collected into an array and the correct date assigned to them. For that, I create a 42 element array using the brilliantly-named function test3.

Here's a screen:
[image]

```
function getFirstDayOfMonth(zeroBasedMonthNum, fullYear)
{
    var monthNames = ['January','Febuary','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
    var dateStr = `${monthNames[zeroBasedMonthNum]} 1, ${fullYear}, 00:00:00`;
    var monthStart = new Date( dateStr );
    return monthStart;
}

function daysInMonth(zeroBasedMonthNumber)
{
    var days = [31,28,31,30,31,30, 31,31,30, 31,30,31 ];
    return days[zeroBasedMonthNumber];
}

function MonthDay(number,isThisMonth)
{
    this.day = number;
    this.thisMonth = isThisMonth;
    return this;
}

function test3(monthIndex, year)
{
    var firstDay = getFirstDayOfMonth(monthIndex, year).getDay();
    if (firstDay == 0)
        firstDay = 6;
    else
        firstDay--;

    var daysFromLastMonth = firstDay;
    var result = [];

    var daysInLastMonth = daysInMonth(monthIndex-1);
    var first = daysInLastMonth - daysFromLastMonth + 1;
    console.log(first);
    for (var i=0; i<daysFromLastMonth; i++)
    {
        //result.push(first+i);
        result.push( new MonthDay(first+i, false) );
    }

    for (var i=1; i<= daysInMonth(monthIndex); i++)
        //result.push( i );
        result.push( new MonthDay(i,true) );

    var daysDone = result.length;
    var daysToGo = (6*7) - daysDone;
    for (var i=1; i<=daysToGo; i++)
        //result.push( i );
        result.push( new MonthDay(i,false) );

    return result;
}
```